# AWStats icons are not showing / Error 404

Tags: 12.10, server, icons, apache2

Edit: This is the solution should anyone have the same problem

After installing and configuring AWStats from the repository, and following instructions from here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AWStats

it will work fine, except the pictures/icons will not be shown (you will get an Error 404).

The proposed configuration of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default is

`Alias /awstatsclasses "/usr/share/awstats/lib/"

Alias /awstatsicons/ "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"

Alias /awstatscss "/usr/share/doc/awstats/examples/css"

ScriptAlias /awstats/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

but the actual URL when I open an image is

http://example.com/**awstats-icon**/other/awstats_logo6.png

edit the default file to make this line has a - and no "s" after "icon":

`Alias /awstatsicons/ to /awstats-icon/`

Then save the file and reload Apache2

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`.

Icons should not be visible.

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question, could you please limit your question to just the details of the problem you encountered? Then, answer your own question separately, below, and accept it. That way people can immediately see that there is an accepted solution.

Comment: My Apache complained about "Options ExecCGI ..." missing a +. The solution is adding this plus: "Options +ExecCGI ..."

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer for AWStats under Ubuntu 12.10. Please see my edited question for details.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please keep the *question* in the question, and the *answer* in the answer. That is, you should edit your question again to remove anything that answers the question, and you should edit this answer to include in it any information that is part of the answer.